# Is there a way to include html file or snippet directly in jade?

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a set of html files, mostly static, I would like to move to my node.js/express/jade project. What's the right way to include html file or snippet directly in jade? I don't want to translate existing html file to jade?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You should be able to simply [`include` it](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/tree/0.33.0#includes) within a jade template:

> As mentioned `include` can be used to include other content such as html or css. By providing an extension, Jade will read that file in, apply any [filter](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/tree/0.33.0#filters7) matching the file's extension, and insert that content into the output.

```
html
  // ...
  body
    // ...
    //- html files have no filter and are included verbatim
    include content.html
```

Comment: Does this mean you can import raw SVGs into Jade markup in this way?

Comment: I've still found that indentation on the included html file needs to be correctly formatted. Weird but true.

Comment: How to use `include` with the file name in a variable?

Answer (score 7):

Use `:verbatim` before the exact html code or snippet directly in jade.

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  :verbatim
    {% include head.html %}
  body
    :verbatim
    {{ content }}

  :verbatim
    {% include footer.html %}
```

**Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">{% include head.html %}
  <body>{{ content }}
  </body>{% include footer.html %}
</html>
```

Comment: You are awesome to know about :verbatim. I can not find this in the jade-lang.com documentation, but it certainly works. It's the only reasonably maintainable way I've found to include multi-line code fragments and other pre-formatted text in Jade.

Comment: What version does :verbatim apply to pls? Jade 1.11.0 doesnt understand that declaration

Comment: The new version of Jade, which was renamed to Pug, does not understand :verbatim.

Answer (score 4):

In my .jade file, I had to do something like this:

```
:verbatim
   !{editorBody}
```

.. where *editorBody* is provided via res.render() call :

```
var editorBody = '<p>Hello</p>';

return res.render('user/user_profile', {editorBody : editorBody});
```

Comment: What version does :verbatim apply to pls? Jade 1.11.0 doesnt understand that declaration